# How to club the average value (in another column) for rows having same values in csv file using python/pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have generated a CSV shown below :-

```
term      unique_identity     score1     score2    score3
abc       uid_1                8           0.5      0.8
abc       uid_1                22          0.65     0.42
abc       uid_1                17          0.78     0.48
abc       uid_2                12          0.62     0.45
abc       uid_2                13          0.49     0.21
abc       uid_2                15          0.50     0.10
abc       uid_3                12          0.49     0.20
abc       uid_3                13          0.60     0.10
abc       uid_3                31          0.21     0.56
```

---

However, I want to club the value of each score for all the unique identities, somewhat like below :-

```
term   unique_id   average_score1    average_score2            average_score3
abc    uid_1       15.66(8+22+17/3)  0.6433(0.5+0.65+0.78/3)   0.566(0.8+.42+.48/3)
abc    uid_2       13.33(12+13+15/3) 0.5366(0.62+0.49+0.50/3)  0.2533(0.45+.21+.10/3)
```

I tried using `.groupby()` in pandas but failed to get anything like this.

Comment: Do you want to keep the `term` column in the output? It has the same value for all entries in the sample you have given.

Comment: Yeah I want term to be same in a column but uid should be different for each term.

Comment: If `term` is going to be same then you can ignore it. `df.groupby("unique_identity").mean()` will give you the required result except showing the `term` columns

Comment: Thanks @DivyeshPeshavaria but it didnt worked again as I receive below error 
KeyError: 'unique_id'

# importing pandas package
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")




df_1 = df.groupby("unique_id").mean()

df_1.to_csv("updated_file_name.csv", index=True,sep='\t')

Comment: check the columns in your input CSV, it is `unique_identity` not `unique_id`. You need to give the correct column name as argument to `.groupby()`.